# Any way to fix the image position with jquery

Tags: jquery-validate

I have the image at specific position e,g

```
img {

position:absolute;
top:150px;

}
```

Is there any to scroll the image with text scrolling so that image always stays at same position with respect to screen.

I don't want to use position fixed

Comment: Why don't you want to use `position: fixed`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to give it `fixed` position:

```
img {
  position:fixed;
  top:150px;
  left:200px;
}
```

And then adjust the `top` and `left` values accordingly.

No need for jQuery but if you still want, you can do like:

```
$(function(){
  $('#img_id').css({
   position:'fixed',
   top:'150px',
   left: '200px'
  });
});
```